# How to make a keras NN that chooses between multiple options?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Im trying to make an NN with keras that predicts the best move for a checkers game. I have a method to get all viable moves that are possible and the NN should choose the best one out of the N possible moves.

Now the problem: The input has (for this example simplified) a shape of (6,6) for the board-state, (1,1) for the player and (N,6,6) for the possible action-states. The wanted output would be a softmax of length N.

How should I do that? Since Im using a Dense layer later on, the inputs should have a defined shape, also it isnt neccessary for one action-state to know about the others.

I had the idea of inserting just the board-state and one action-state at the time and calculating a single number which then gets compared to the other numbers, but having one NN to predict the right move from all possible moves seemed to be the more logical solution.

Comment: Neural networks actually aren't very good for exploring combinatorial game theory (and neither are genetic algorithms). The whole point of neural networks is that you can train them to find pattern-matching rules without ever knowing what those rules are. (Of course neural networks are very good for exploring how neural networks deal with combinatorial game theory, but that's not the same thing.).

Comment: nice to know, but I kind of really want to use them and thought, that the solution with multiple options could fit neatly into a policy based implementation of the NN